# Convert Column Number to Related Column Letters in Google Spreadsheet with Ballerina

Tags: wso2, spreadsheet, google-sheets-api, ballerina, wso2-esb

How to convert the column number of a spreadsheet to the relative column header letters in Ballerina?

e.g.:

1. **1** to **A**
2. **2** to **B**
3. **26** to **Z**
4. **27** to **AA**
5. **52** to **AZ**
6. **53** to **BA**

Column number can be arbitrarily high where the number of letters are also not limited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the *convColNumToChars* function as follows.

```
function convColNumToChars(int columnNumber) returns string {
    if (columnNumber != 0) {
        return convColNumToChars((columnNumber-1)/26) + genAsciiChar(columnNumber%26);
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}

function genAsciiChar(int charCode) returns string {
    string[] charSet = ["Z", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O",
        "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y"];
    return charSet[charCode];
}
```